# Can I replace the HeaderTemplate within the Content section

Tags: wpf

I'm using an application framework that sets up a HeaderedContentControl and places my usercontrol in the content section.

Is there any way I can change the Header template from within the Content section?

Comment: Please, share your code with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot set any property or modify the `HeaderTemplate` of the parent `HeaderedContentControl` in the `Content` "section" in the XAML markup.

What you can to is to programmatically handle the `Loaded` event for the content, i.e. the `UserControl` in this case, and get a reference to the parent `HeaderedContentControl` using the `VisualTreeHelper` class.